# Unset array value in session on a href click

Tags: php, arrays, session

I got a session with an array of id's in it. These ids are used to display products on a quote page (using id in ($sessionarray)). Now I added a remove icon and I would like to remove ids when that link is clicked. Can this be done without using javascript?

All products are loaded from my query like so:

```
if(count($_SESSION['product']) == 0){
    echo 'No products added';
}else{
    foreach($offertecr as $product){
        if (strlen($product['introtext']) > 100){   
           $shortcat = substr($product['introtext'], 0, 100) . '...';
        }else{
            $shortcat = $product['introtext'];
        }
        $offerte_imgs = $product['image_intro']; // Get image parameters of the article
        $offertepic = json_decode($offerte_imgs); // Split the parameters apart

        if($offertepic->{'image_intro'} != ''){
            $image = 'cms/'.$offertepic->{'image_intro'};
        }else{
            $image = 'http://www.website.nl/_extern/web/cms/images/Producten/Untitled-7.jpg';
        }

        if($product['id'] != ''){
            $offerteoverzicht .= '
            <div class="row productofferte">
                <div class="col-md-6 offerteimg">
                    <img src="'.$image.'">
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    <p style="font-weight:bold;">'.$product['title'].' <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></p>
                    <p>'.$shortcat.'</p>
                </div>
            </div>';    
        }
    }   
}
```

When the link in the description is pressed I would like the id to be removed from the session (which is an array).

Code I used (on which I have to press the remove button twice for it to have effect):

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $productID  = $_GET['id'];
    $key=array_search($_GET['id'],$_SESSION['product']);
    if($key!==false)
    unset($_SESSION['product'][$key]);
    $_SESSION["product"] = array_values($_SESSION["product"]);
}
```

Comment: Yes but it will involve a round trip to the server and a page repaint

Comment: @RiggsFolly You mean I have to redo the code for it to work?

Comment: Looks like you have an answer that basically covers what I was hinting at, see if that works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is commented and would give you (kind of) an idea on how you could go about doing that with PHP...

```
<?php

    // IF YOU WISH TO USE PHP TO DELETE YOUR PRODUCT FROM THE SESSION, 
    // YOU COULD CHANGE THE VALUE OF THE href ATTRIBUTE OF YOUR LINK 
    // TO CONTAIN THE PRODUCT ID WHICH WOULD BE USED TO DELETE THAT SPECIFIC PRODUCT.
    // IN THIS CASE, CLICKING ON THE DELETE BUTTON WOULD REDIRECT BACK TO THIS PAGE
    // BUT WITH SOME QUERY PARAMETERS ATTACHED TO THE URL

    // SO; FIRST, AT THE TOP OF THE FILE WE CHECK IF THE QUERY PARAM IS THERE:
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        // THEN WE KNOW THE ID OF THE PRODUCT WE WANT TO DELETE
        $productID  = $_GET['id'];

        // NOW YOU CAN VERY EASILY DELETE THIS ID FROM THE SESSION LIKE SO:
        // IF WE HAVE THE $productID IN OUR SESSION: $_SESSION['product']
        // WE CAN SIMPLY UNSET IT....
        if( $index = array_search($productID, $_SESSION['product']) ) {
            $_SESSION['product'][$index] = null;
            unset($_SESSION['product'][$index]);
        } 
    }

    if(count($_SESSION['product']) == 0){
        echo 'No products added';
    }else{
        foreach($offertecr as $product){
            if (strlen($product['introtext']) > 100){
                $shortcat = substr($product['introtext'], 0, 100) . '...';
            }else{
                $shortcat = $product['introtext'];
            }
            $offerte_imgs = $product['image_intro']; // Get image parameters of the article
            $offertepic = json_decode($offerte_imgs); // Split the parameters apart

            if($offertepic->{'image_intro'} != ''){
                $image = 'cms/'.$offertepic->{'image_intro'};
            }else{
                $image = 'http://www.website.nl/_extern/web/cms/images/Producten/Untitled-7.jpg';
            }

            if($product['id'] != ''){
                $deleteLink        = "./?id=" . $product['id'];
                $offerteoverzicht .= '
            <div class="row productofferte">
                <div class="col-md-6 offerteimg">
                    <img src="'.$image.'">
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    <p style="font-weight:bold;">'.$product['title'].' 
                        <a href="' . $deleteLink . '">
                            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                    <p>'.$shortcat.'</p>
                </div>
            </div>';
            }
        }
    }
```

**NOTES**

```
        // THIS IS THE PART THAT  MAKES THIS WORK
        // NOTICE THE $deleteLink WITHIN THE href ATTRIBUTE OF THE ANCHOR TAG..
        $deleteLink        = "./?id=" . $product['id'];

        '<p style="font-weight:bold;">'.$product['title'].' 
            <a href="' . $deleteLink . '">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </p>';
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to delete a product from my database, but unset it from my session array.

Comment: @twan  The same Principles also apply in both cases... all you have to do is just unset the id within the if Clause... The Code was updated to that effect.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work, only problem, I have to press the link twice for the product to be removed from the session. Any idea why? I added the code I used in the original answer.

Comment: when I press the remove icon the page refreshed but the product is still there, then I press it again and only then it is removed.

Comment: still the same, and I can't remove the top product, only the items below that (after clicking two times)